Prevent Teams from renaming files that are emailed to a channel
I've emailed a file named My Dummy Report into a Teams Channel.  Teams automatically renames the file to something stupid: My Dummy Report_1725951453
It's important for me that the file is not renamed.  This is Microsoft's reason for ballsing up my process.
My requirement:
email in a monthly report from a financial system in .xlsx format.  Same file name needed, as the Excel file will be plugged into a PowerBI report.  If the new monthly file name changes, PowerBI won't find it.
I suppose I could try using Power Automate to trim off the unwanted suffix from the file name, but does anyone have another suggestion to tackle this?  Have Microsoft really been this short-sighted; launching Teams with the aim of helping you link together different stuff in one place, then immediately torpedoing you!?
Thanks
p.s. apologies for the lack of a double-space after a full-stops in my question, Stack Exchange is forcibly messing up my punctuation.

